# Change HTTP/S ports in OS X Server?

Tags: macos, networking, dns, port-forwarding, port

I am setting up OS X Server on a local computer (for managing a few devices.) I contacted my ISP to allow me to set up port forwarding, and they said that incoming ports 80 and 443 are disabled. Which are the ports that the OS X Interface runs on.

My first step was to forward a random port (eg 1234) to port 80 internally. After, I went to http://example.com:1234/profilemanager. It went through, but none of the resources were loading on port 1234, because I can't specify a port in OS X Server.

My question is - is it possible to either specify a default HTTP/S port in OS X Server, or can I somehow tell my domain to point to a port through the domain's DNS?

Thanks!